# Why does form.is_valid() update the related model for Django ModelForms?

Tags: django, django-forms

Can anyone explain this?  It's really unintuitive that a form validation method would update the related model.  I understand it doesn't commit to the database, but why even modify the model in memory?  Why not do it with form.save()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reason is this:

> The first time you call is_valid() or
>   access the errors attribute of a
>   ModelForm has always triggered form
>   validation, but as of Django 1.2, it
>   will also trigger model validation.
>   This has the side-effect of cleaning
>   the model you pass to the ModelForm
>   constructor. For instance, calling
>   is_valid() on your form will convert
>   any date fields on your model to
>   actual date objects.

From [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-is-valid-method-and-errors). Logically, this does actually make sense. Suppose I have a model like this:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    Somefield = models.CharField(unique=True)
```

Then as far as the modelform is concerned, validating the field `TextInputField` would work for any value. However, from the model's perspective, not any value will do - that value must be unique.

The validation mechanisms are described [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects). Basically, calling `full_clean` on a model causes that model to check its own fields as per the OO paradigm. So for this reason, the in memory image of the model can be updated and validating it will check it can actually be written to the database.

Thus it makes sense, because your guard:

```
if form.is_valid():
```

Really ought to ensure that:

```
    form.save()
```

Can actually happen.